# sorry, unimplemented: non-trivial designated initializers not supported

Tags: c, embedded, system, atmega

I am trying to configure ADC on ATMEGA328 with C and I get on this line:

`FILE usart0_str = FDEV_SETUP_STREAM(USART0SendByte, NULL, _FDEV_SETUP_WRITE);`

The following error:

`sorry, unimplemented: non-trivial designated initializers not supported
FILE usart0_str = FDEV_SETUP_STREAM(USART0SendByte, NULL, _FDEV_SETUP_WRITE);
                   ^`

I really do not understand the Error, I tried on Google to search for it, but did not found similar to this and I am sure that this happens because I do not understand this error.

Here is the Whole code:

```
#ifndef F_CPU
#define F_CPU 16000000UL
#endif

#include <stdio.h>
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>
#define USART_BAUDRATE 9600
#define UBRR_VALUE ( ( ( F_CPU / ( USART_BAUDRATE * 16UL ) ) ) - 1 )
#define VREF 5
#define POT 10000

void initADC( void );
uint16_t readADC( uint8_t ADCchannel );
void USART0Init(void);
int USART0SendByte( char u8Data, FILE *stream );
void setUpLED ( void );

FILE usart0_str = FDEV_SETUP_STREAM( USART0SendByte, NULL, _FDEV_SETUP_WRITE );

int main( void )
{
    double vbg, potval;

    initADC();
    USART0Init();

    stdout = &usart0_str;
    setUpLED ();

    while ( 1 )
    {
        potval = (double)POT / 1024 * readADC(0);
        printf("Potentiometer value = %u Ohm\n", (uint16_t)potval);

        vbg = (double)VREF / 1024 * readADC(14);
        printf("Vbg = %4.2fV\n", vbg);

        _delay_ms(1000);
    }
}

void setUpLED ( void )
{
    DDRB  |= ( 1 << PB0 );
    PORTB |= ( 1 << PB0 );
}

void initADC( void )
{
    ADMUX  |= ( 1 << REFS0 );
    ADCSRA |= ( 1 << ADPS2 ) | ( 1 << ADPS1 ) | ( 1 << ADPS0 ); ///16000000/128=125kHz
    ADCSRA |= ( 1 << ADEN );
}

uint16_t readADC( uint8_t ADCchannel )
{
    ADMUX = ( ADMUX & 0xF0 ) | ( ADCchannel & 0x0F );
    ADCSRA |= ( 1 << ADSC );
    while ( ADCSRA & ( 1 << ADSC ) );
    return ADC;
}

int USART0SendByte( char u8Data, FILE *stream )
{
    if ( u8Data == '\n' )
    {
        USART0SendByte( '\r', stream );
    }

    while ( !( UCSR0A & ( 1 << UDRE0 ) ) ) { };
    UDR0 = u8Data;
    return 0;
}

void USART0Init(void)
{
    UBRR0H = (uint8_t)(UBRR_VALUE >> 8);
    UBRR0L = (uint8_t)UBRR_VALUE;

    UCSR0C |= (1 << UCSZ01) | (1 << UCSZ00);
    UCSR0B |= (1 << RXEN0) | (1 << TXEN0);
}`
```

If I compile it with `codeblocks` everything works fine, but I use an arduino board as a programmer and the arduino IDE also.

Why I am getting this Error?

Comment: It means the compiler does not fully support the feature (designated initializers) that you’re using, and knows that it doesn’t, and is indirectly apologizing for not doing so.  It probably has some limited support for them, but you’re pushing it too hard.  Simplify.  But I’m not sure how.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Any Ideas about how to fix it? Other approach maybe?

Comment: Do you have the definition of FDEV_SETUP_STREAM() ?

Comment: @BjornA. Yes, I mean I tried `#define FDEV_SETUP_STREAM   ( put, get, rwflag )` but it does not work. Took it [From Here](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__stdio.html#gaea2b6be92ead4673bc487b271b7227fb)

Comment: Aside: Tip on baud rate generation: With `#define UBRR_VALUE ( ( ( F_CPU / ( USART_BAUDRATE * 16UL ) ) ) - 1 )` the baud is formed from a truncated quotient.  Better to form a _rounded_ quotient.  `a/b` --> `(a + b/2)/b`.

Comment: @chux I am not sure I undestand what you mean. This is what you mean: `#define UBRR_VALUE( ( ( F_CPU  + ( USART_BAUDRATE * 16UL ) ) / 2 ) / ( USART_BAUDRATE * 16UL ) - 1 )` ?

Comment: Yes -at least close.  How about in steps: `#define BR_DEN (USART_BAUDRATE * 16UL) #define UBRR_VALUE (((F_CPU + BR_DEN/2) / BR_DEN) - 1)`?

Comment: @chux I see now. You are right Sir, Thank You

Comment: There's usually a formula for how to calculate the baudrate prescaler in the manual.

Comment: The feature "designated initializers" seems to be present in some library. It is a C feature not supported by C++. You might have to compile the libraries as C. Anyway, it is better to entirely avoid streams on embedded systems. Writing a UART driver yourself is usually the way to go.

Comment: @JohnDoe, did you get this to work?